# Track circulation of a token in ethereum blockchain using web3 / rpc

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, rpc, web3js

I create my own token and I need to watch the entire circulation of this token. Exchanges can be in the shape of a tree. Having the address of a participant, I have to find the whole branch up to him. That's how they got those tokens at him. I have to see the transactions' hashes, and I know only contract address and wallet address of a participant.

Can it be resolved using web3 / rpc? An example of a tree that might be, just here will be my token.

[image]